# discord.js user.speaking isn't working

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
//function fires after special command every 100 milliseconds
function searchSpeaking(roleSpeak){

    //checks every channel; giving you member-channel and its chanId-id
    bot.channels.forEach((channel, chanId) => {
        //filters out text channels
        if (channel.type == 'voice'){
            //checks every member in voice channel; giving you guildMember-user and his/her id
            channel.members.forEach((guildMember, memberId) => {
                //debug
                console.log(guildMember.nickname, guildMember.speaking)
                console.log("-----------------------------------")
                //activates when user speaks DOESN'T WORK
                if (guildMember.speaking){
                    //adds 'score' it means how mayn milli seconds user talks
                    scoreboard[memberId] += 100
                    console.log("user is speaking!")
                    //if user talks for over 30s = 30 000 milliseconds and has option to talk
                    if ((scoreboard[memberId] > 30 * 1000) && guildMember.roles.has(roleSpeak.id)){
                        //reset his score and remove his option to speak
                        scoreboard[memberId] = 0
                        guildMember.removeRole(roleSpeak)
                    }
                }
                //if user isnt talking because his option/role to talk was removed
                else if (!(guildMember.roles.has(roleSpeak.id))){
                    //we messure how much time he/she has been muted/without talking option
                    scoreboard[memberId] += 100
                    //if he/she was muted for a minute he/she will get his option/role to talk back 
                    if (scoreboard[id] > 60 * 1000){
                        //reset score and give back role
                        scoreboard[memberId] = 0
                        guildMember.addRole(roleSpeak)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    })
}
```

So in the line under a comment ( // ) stating that this doesn't work is an if statement that never passes even tho users are speaking in channels. It is console.loging as false as well (obvious). So i can't figure out why as i understand the docs it should turn to true every time member speaks. I will just say this again (as it says in first code comment) this function fires every 100ms = 0.1s and gets a role it is supposed to change based on score further explained in code comments.

Thanks for any help working with `.speaking`!

Answer (score 1):

With the current API, there is **no way** to know if a user is talking in a voice channel **without joining the voice channel**.
You would need to **join** a voice channel, get a list of the users that are talking, and then switch to another channel (if there are any members in that channel).
You would probably get **rate limited** very quickly using this method.
Only way without joining the channels, would be getting the list of members in voice channels, and filter those with microphone muted. You still wouldn't know if they are really talking.

If you would want to join the channel and "listen" to the speaking, you could use the event [`guildMemberSpeaking`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberSpeaking). This would activate whenever a user starts/stops talking in the voice channel you are.